# Sort a MySQL result based on total count of another result

Tags: php, mysql

I have tables `tbl_posts` and `tbl_comments` with primary keys `post_id` and `comment_id` respectively. I tried this code:

```
$allPosts=mysql_query("
    select c.comment_id, post_id, count(*)
    from post u,
    comments c
    where u.comment_id = c.comment_id
    group by comment_id, post_id
    LIMIT 10
");
```

but I have no clue what it does. How do I combine two tables so that the total comments determines the order of the listed posts from `tbl_posts`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's more readable if you separate per lines and work with joins

```
select c.comment_id, post_id, count(*) 
from post u join comments c 
on u.comment_id = c.comment_id 
group by comment_id, post_id LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have tables named **tbl_comment** and **tbl_post** but your query has them listed as just **comment and post**.

```
select c.comment_id, post_id, count(*) 
from tbl_post u, tbl_comments c 
where u.comment_id = c.comment_id 
group by comment_id, post_id LIMIT 10


$allPosts=mysql_query("select c.comment_id, post_id, count(*) from tbl_post u, tbl_comments c where u.comment_id = c.comment_id group by comment_id, post_id LIMIT 10");
```

This just fixes the query so it runs, and does not address any content issues you may have, namely the group by on both (what I am guessing) are primary keys.

** EDIT **
To fix the sorting try:

```
SELECT tbl_post.comment_id, count(*)  
FROM tbl_post, tbl_comments
WHERE tbl_post.comment_id = tbl_comment.comment_id  
GROUP BY comment_id LIMIT 10
ORDER BY count(*)
```

Comment: Yes, the tables are tbl_comments and tbl_posts. I tried your suggestion and it did not work. Is there a good site that explains what you did, or do you have the time to explain how combining works?

Comment: In the FROM clause you list the tables you want to reference and in this case you create an alias for each table.. U for post and c for comment.  In the WHERE clause is where the join takes place.  Where every tbl_comment.comment_id has a matching row in tbl_post.comment_id a value is returned.

Comment: Are you getting an error or just no rows returned?  If you are getting an empty set back then I would verify you have a common comment_id value in both tables.

Comment: Thanks, that what I thought. I am getting a this guy: Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/username/public_html/bfm/includes/home.php on line 88 . Line 88 is: if(mysql_num_rows($allPosts)){...

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of your SQL:

You are selecting column **comment_id** from table **comments**, column **post_id** from table **post** using a inner join, grouping by **comment_id**, **post_id**, with a limit of 10 results.

I would try:

```
$allPosts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT c.comment_id, u.post_id, COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM post u 
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.comment_id = u.comment_id 
GROUP BY c.comment_id, u.post_id)
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10");
```